# Java Cucumber: creating scenario outlines with dynamic examples

Tags: java, cucumber, outline

We have a test where basically we need to input a specific value in a web site and make sure another value comes out.  The data of the input-output for this is stored in an XML file.

Now we can create a single Scenario that runs once and loops through, submitting each value however we run into some reporting problems, if 2 out of 100 pairs fail we want to know which ones and not just have an assertion error for the whole scenario.

We would get much clearer reporting using a Scenario Outline where all the values are in the examples table. then the scenario itself runs repeatedly and we can fail an individual set as an assertion error and have that kick back clearly in a report.

Problem: we do not want to hard code all the values from the xml into the .feature.  it's noisy but also if the values change it's slow to update. we would rather just provide the XML parse it and go, if things change we just drop in an updated XML.

Is there a way to create dynamic examples where we can run the scenario repeatedly, one for each data case, without explicitly defining it in the examples table ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Cucumber for this is a bad idea. You should test this functionality lower down your stack with a unit test.

At some point in your code, after the user has input their value, the value will be passed to a method/function that will return your answer. This is the place to do this sort of testing.

A cucumber test going through the whole stack will upwards of 3 orders of magnitude slower than a well written unit tests. So you could test thousands of pairs of values in your unit test in the time it takes to run one single cuke.

If you do this sort of testing in Cucumber you will quickly end up with a test suite that takes far too long to run, or that can only be run quickly at great expense. This is very damaging to a project.

Cuking should be about one happy path (The user can enter a value and see the result) and maybe a sad path (the user enters a bad value and sees an error/explanation). Anything else needs to be pushed down to unit tests.

Comment: In this case the data is configured data outside of the app so it changes without a deployment or any formal process (this app hardly ever deploys), we are using our test suite to do nightly runs so runtime is not an issue just test maintenance as well as reporting when an issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

The [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) framework does exactly what you want to do in your project. The NoraUi code is open source. If you have questions about this framework, you can post an issue with the tag "Question"